# Slope raster seems to come out distorted?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, slope, noise

I've been trying to get a slope raster from a DEM, so I can reclassify it and aggregate it with land use data.

The problem is that my slope raster seems to have a lot of distortion (diagonal lines). I've tried changing some settings but I really have no idea what can be causing this. I'm using a projected CRS, EPSG 31983. I've got the DEM from whole state where I live in Brazil, then I had to clip it to my AOI, and that is all the processing I made with the DEM before trying to get the slope.

Some information about the DEM file from the metadata:

> Driver: GDAL provider
>   GTiff GeoTIFF
>
> Dataset Description
>   /Users/Guilherme/Desktop/FINAL/DEM/DEM_SIRGAS_CLIPPED.tif
>
> AREA_OR_POINT=Area
>   DataType=Generic
>
> HighCellSize=0.039888
>   LowCellSize=0.000277
>   MaxCellSize=1.994400
>
> Band 1
>   SourceBandIndex=0
>
> Dimensions - X: 692 Y: 346 Bands: 1
>
> Origin: 227546,7.41239e+06
>
> Pixel Size: 28.8724,-28.8724
>
> No Data Value: 0
>
> Data Type: Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
>
> Pyramid overviews
>
> Layer Spatial Reference System: +proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
>
> Layer Extent (layer original source projection) - 
>   227546.4710596329532564,7402400.2644091211259365 : 247526.1508292471116874,7412390.1042939284816384
>
> Band No: 1
>   Min Val: 531.9765014648
>   Max Val: 960.2605590820
>   Range: 428.2840576172
>   Mean: 608.2492439474
>   Sum of squares: 1395234469.1412367821
>   Standard Deviation: 76.3367047628
>   Sum of all cells: 145634332.9768066406
>   Cell Count: 239432

DEM file:

[image: DEM file]

Slope generated from DEM (a lot of odd diagonal lines):

[image: Slope generated from DEM]

<sub>EDIT:</sub>

I went to the source again, and got the raw DEM to process/clip it again. This time around everything seemed to work just fine. I believe what happened was some kind of mismanage when warping the raster.

I didn't get the chance to try Freighty's solution because SAGA and Orfeo are not working properly for me, but I believe if you have access to them, it's a feasible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a play with your data and there are stripping errors in your DEM. Where did you obtain it from?

You can reduce the errors by smoothing your raster either using the 'Simple Filter' SAGA tool in the processing toolbox; or the "Smoothing' Orfeo Toolbox, again in the processing toolbox in QGIS if you have both providers installed. Then you can calculate your slope raster from this smoothed dataset. However you will lose information so this may not be desirable.

You can look at other methods such as using a fast fourier transformation to remove the stripping as outlined here http://www.ctmap.com/assets/pdfprojects/destripe.pdf

Comment: Well, I think this might solve my problem. I don't care about losing some information. However, I can't access both SAGA tools and Orfeo from the toolbox... maybe something related to my mac as I've seen here. Are there any other tools that can do that? The link you gave me is not working here.